# PhpStorm - Create a method from it's call

Tags: phpstorm

For fast class prototyping I'm looking for a way to create methods declaration from it's call.

Example :

I'm writing.

```
$this->doStuff($action);
```

Magic happens. Following code is generated :

```
function doStuff ($action) {
    //My cursor is here
}
```

Is it possible with PhpStorm ?

I saw code extraction implementation, it's nice, but it's not the same. Getters and setters inserting is not the same also, because a class property should be declared initially.

Comment: Your question is confusing. PHPStorm is an IDE. PHP is the language, and you are using PHPStorm to create&edit PHP applications?

Comment: @Ok, I'll remove php tag from the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> while having caret on such call and choose appropriate option from there.

Comment: Great. Do You know, by the way, there the template of new method could be adjusted ?

Comment: `Settings | File and Code Templates` maybe?

Comment: There are templates for getters and settters, but not just for new method.

Comment: I was expecting that "PHP Implemented Method Body" would work here -- apparently it does not. Oh well -- you can file Feature Request ticket to their Issue Tracker at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI (but check for already existing tickets **first**)