# PhpStorm 8 - how to autocomplete by strings written in file

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

So here is the example:

I have written

```
private function test() {
        $this->haha();
    }
```

Now I write function "haha"

```
private function ha
```

and I want autocomplete it to "haha". It does not suggest. In Sublime Text 2 it was easily working I think.

Maybe there is some configuration or plugin needed? Otherwise this looks great, but autocompletion is not too great so far.

**Update:**

Comments and answer partially answered my question, but now I give another example to ilustrate the problem maybe better:

```
$a = array('test');
$b = array('t
```

Tried with sublime - after in second array writing letter 't' and pressing tab - it autocompleted to test.

With PhpStorm - this did not work. How do you make to work this?

**Update:**

I think I found what I want partly. It is if during menu: code > completion > Cyclic expand word.

Or with keyboard: Alt + / and Alt + Shift + /

But what is missing - when typing - it does not show the menu to choose from. So now the question arises - how to get menu showing of words as you type the first letter like sublime does?

Comment: Why do you need to write `private function ha`? PhpStorm can create whole function declaration for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23090465/783119 -- that's what I meant.

Comment: What about german keyboards on macOS? To get a `/` I need to press `Shift` + `7`. If I hit `Alt` + `Shift` + `7` I get a backslash ``\``.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than type `private function ha` would it be acceptable to click on the `This->haha()` method call  and have PhpStorm generate the method for you?

If yes, press Alt-Enter when your cursor is on 'haha' and you'll be given one option in a dropdown: *'Add Method';* just press enter and PhpStorm will add to the end of your class.